# Updater in a java program

Tags: java, client-server

How do I create an updater for some files in a java program?

That is, I have:

```
program.jar -> my java program
dir_xml / -> list of xml files that can be updated
```

Comment: You need to explain a bit more what you meant by "updater". You want to update some file time stamps?

Comment: Essentially what happens in the anti-virus program for windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [Java Web Start.](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/index-jsp-136112.html).  It essentially does what Swaranga Sarma suggests above.

It takes care of deploying your program and keeping your program files updated.  It even ensures the client's java version is correct.

Answer (score -2):

Code a client making a `GET` request to the server. `GET` the `http` response from the server and `GET` the file.